# Dependency fields on add people page

Tags: entities

For a project I need to register new customers. That customer belongs to a store chain, and that store chain is connected with a store.

I only want to display the store's which are linked to the storechain on the add people page.

What is the best way to fix this? Conditional fields module doesn't work for this :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps the [Profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module create a profile per store and then show the right store profile fields on the registration page, if needed to work with your logic you could place specific stores on specific registration paths with [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath).

**EDIT**

> What is the best way to fix this? ... big changes like this aren't possible ...

You asked a problem, I offered a solution. My opinion on the best way to fix your problem is to do some re-engineering of your site. If you disagree that's fine -- best of luck on finding a solution to your problem.

Modules such as [views bulk operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert) are examples of modules which exist to make sweeping changes of a website feasible (although not without coordination on your behalf). What you say isn't possible -- I say is merely difficult.

Comment: The application is already running so big changes like this aren't possible anymore I think.

The store chain and store are content types

Comment: @user3428971 I have revised my answer. goodluck on your project.